# How to extract text from multiple lines including the first and last word?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to extract part of a long text, such as information about caring for a plant. The text contains paragraphs and blank lines. I am not able to capture the specific text I want, the second problem is that the last word isn't showing in the extracted text, and the last problem is when my search starts at the beginning of the line.

I tried searching for the text I want to extract by using a word that isn't at the beginning of the line, it worked except that the end of the desired text is missing a word, and if that word is on new line, it won't show any results at all.
I was using https://scriptun.com/tools/php/preg_match for testing

//The first word to start the search is 'How to'. And I want to capture it as well 
// The second word where the text I want ends is '(optional):'

```
'/(?=How to).*?\s(?=\(optional\):)/'
```

**The sample text I am using to test is:**

> //Text comes before this..
>
> How to care for Split Leaf Plant
>
> The Split leaf philodendron, also called monstera deliciosa or  swiss
>   cheese plant, is a large, popular, easy- care houseplant that is not
>   really in the philodendron family. There is a great deal of confusion
>   about what to call this plant; the various names have become
>   inter-changeable over the years.
>
> Here is more info (optional):
>
> //And more text goes here

I want to extract all the text from the word 'How to' ending with '(optional):'. Regardless of how many lines or paragraphs are in between

**The expected extracted text:**

> How to care for Split Leaf Plant
>
> The Split leaf philodendron, also called monstera deliciosa or  swiss
>   cheese plant, is a large, popular, easy- care houseplant that is not
>   really in the philodendron family. There is a great deal of confusion
>   about what to call this plant; the various names have become
>   inter-changeable over the years.
>
> Here is more info (optional):

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy.  You can use the following pattern:

https://regex101.com/r/TjE2x8/2

Pattern: `^How to[\w\W]+?\(optional\):$`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, it is now working as expected.

Comment: If this answers your question you can mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:  `^How to(?:.|\R)*optional\):$`

[demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1aR8jg/1)

Explanation:

- `^` match the first instance where  `How to` appears at the beginning of the line
- `(?: )` non capturing group. We need it because of the following `OR` instruction which is the pipe `|`. But we don't need to capture the contents. That's why we use `?:` after the first parenthesis.
- `.` every character
- `|` or
- `\R` every kind of new line
- `*` make sure to capture zero to every instance of the group
- `optional\):$` match the word `optional` with parenthesis (escaped, because it is not an instruction) `\)` and a colon `:` at the very end of the text `$`

Pattern 2: `/^How to.*optional\):$/ms`

[demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1aR8jg/2/)

This pattern is even simpler, but requires the `m` and `s` flag to be set in order to match multiline and the `.` character class to match new lines.

Comment: `(?:.|\R)*` is inefficient (881 steps) compared with `[\w\W]+?` (382 steps) but you second pattern is really better (64 steps). But you don't distinguish 2 or more paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, it is now working as expected.